# Android: Where to find the RadioButton Drawable?

Tags: android, radio-button, drawable

Ok, I am trying to create a custom view called `CheckedRelativeLayout`.

It's purpose is the same as a `CheckedTextView`, to be able to use it in a list of items you want selected or in a `Spinner`.

It's all working fine now, I extended `RelativeLayout` and implemented `Checkable` interface.

However, I am stuck on a quite simple problem: Where can I find the `Drawable` that `CheckedTextView` and `RadioButton` use?

I looked at the sourcecode of both, and they seem to use `com.android.internal.R`. Well... that's internal stuff. So I can't access it.

Any way to get these Drawables or solve the problem somehow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

look under SDK folder /platforms/android-2.0/data/res/
you can access them by either android.R.drawable ( if public ) or need to copy them as drawable to your project

Comment: That's great. I found them. Also found the corresponding `R.drawable.btn_radio`. But that's just one. There are `btn_radio_off.png`files etc. How can I access those? Is there something like statemanagement?

Comment: it's a stateful drawable. It changes the state based on the state of the View. If you look at it in SDK folder it's defined as XML. By looking to the XML you can see which actual png are being used ( they are in drawable-hdpi/mdpi folders. Stateful drawable are simply awesome and you can do same stuff with colors too.

Comment: To use "btn_radio" for current theme you can use "?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle" as your drawable.

Answer (score 5):

For sake of completeness:

Here some code pieces that show how you I got it working with above accepted answer.

```
 //Image Setup (Once when creating this view)
 ImageView indicator = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.RadioStatusImage);
 indicator.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_radio));

 //State Change (In some other method)
  android.R.attr.state_checked
  if (isChecked)
  {
     indicator.setImageState(android.R.attr.state_checked, false);
  }
  else
  {
     indicator.setImageState(View.ENABLED_STATE_SET, false);
  }
  invalidate();
```

Answer (score 2):

To use the new default animated radio button drawable, the correct answer is in the comment of @sidon:

`?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle`

Using this in the custom position relative to text:

```
<RadioButton
    ...
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:drawableTop="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:button="@null"
    />
```