# Get back the old drawable in Compound button?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-drawable, compound-drawables

How to remove the current drawable and go to old drawable state;

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.opt1);
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.ic_done);
```

For the next question, it should go to the old drawable.

So I have tried `radioButton.setButtonDrawable(0)` but it removed the drawable.
Is there any way to `getDefaultDrawable()` according to `Theme.AppCompat`?

Comment: `radiobutton.setbuttonDrawable(R.drawble.your_original_drawable);`?

Comment: @DerGolem ic_done is my drawble ,it should go back the default state drawable.

Comment: your_original_drawable... http://stackoverflow.com/a/2768055/2649012

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

**Before changing background**

```
RadioButton radioButton;
Drawable defaultRadioButtonBackground = radioButton.getBackground();
```

**When you want to change back to default background**

```
radioButton.setBackground(defaultRadioButtonBackground);
```

Comment: Compound Drawble does not have method called .getButtonDrawable();

Comment: its about radio button.button drawable is used for to  user pressed the button or not .by default it will be round color