# Android: Where to find Seekbar drawable "scrubber_control_normal_holo"

Tags: android, seekbar, seekbar-thumb

My primary problem is I want to increase the size of the thumb of the Seekbar, so I found this post: [Changing size of seekbar thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699951/changing-size-of-seekbar-thumb)

From there it said i can create *thumb_size.xml* and add the below code inside:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <size
            android:height="40dp"
            android:width="40dp" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/scrubber_control_normal_holo"/>
```

However then the Android Studio give me error message saying that it cannot find the

> scrubber_control_normal_holo

Then I find this post: [Android: Where to find the RadioButton Drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767643/android-where-to-find-the-radiobutton-drawable)

However in my SDK folder /platforms/android-17/data/res/drawable folder, I still cannot find this file, I can only find something like:

> seek_thumb.xml

but when I try to use it, it still give me error.

Comment: You can find the source at:  
@android:drawable/scrubber_control_normal_holo
  
Although it does not help you further since the resource is private. Therefore you need to copy it from folder like you already answered

Answer (score 8):

At last I can find the resource images in the following folders (for different device size):

- SDK folder\platforms\android-17\data\res\drawable-hdpi
- SDK folder\platforms\android-17\data\res\drawable-mdpi
- SDK folder\platforms\android-17\data\res\drawable-xhdpi
- SDK folder\platforms\android-17\data\res\drawable-xxhdpi
- SDK folder\platforms\android-17\data\res\drawable-xxxhdpi